# How to connect SSL websocket with mqtt?

Tags: javascript, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I created a self signed certificate and I've been working on the mqtt websockets over SSL/TSL, however I'm unsure exactly where I made an error. On my terminal websocket is open and sends out CONNACK/SUBSCRIBE/PUBLISH etc...

However when I opened up my chrome console log, I got an error saying that

> "websocket connection to 'wss:.//hostname:9001/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

My time is synchronised correctly, and I'm either thinking my certificate has an error or chrome doesn't accept it but if my certificate error, wouldn't it have given an error when I first tried it on regular mosquitto_sub?

Any tips?

Thank you

Comment: The error occurs because Chrome does not trust the certificate - since it is self-signed and not explicitly imported as trusted. This is unrelated to certificate validation done in `mosquitto_sub`.

Comment: Would I have to import the certificate into chrome or is that not necessary? If the certificate validation occurred in mosquitto_sub does this mean the certificate doesn't have any errors?

Comment: A certificate is like a passport. Even if the passport contains no inherent errors itself it will not be necessarily accepted at every border. It will only be accepted if the issuer of the passport is also trusted to only issue passports which match the person. A self-signed certificate is basically saying "trust me", i.e. there is no trusted issuer yet. The browser will trust the certificate only if it is explicitly imported as trusted in the browsers trust store.

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down Steffen! I'm kind of at loss what my next steps are. I added my "hostname" certificate into the authorities part of certificates in chrome but I got another problem now, I got the err_cert_name_invalid and I don't understand, why this addition of certificate changed the problem and how can I fix it? I really want it to work!

Comment: Google says it could be:  It can be a consequence of misconfiguration of certificate in a server. However if that is true, didn't mosquitto_sub validate that this suggestion is not true?

Comment: *"Google says it could be"* - If you would provide the actual link instead of "on the internet" I could point out the error either in the referenced article, your understanding of it or my understanding of your question. As for *"...  I got another problem now"* - I would actually need to see the specific certificate for this and how you use it (i.e. URL used to access it, server configuration, client configuration).